# Deploy Jenkins CI to Heroku

Tags: java, heroku, jenkins

Is there a way to run [Jenkins CI](http://jenkins-ci.org/) as an Heroku app?

It is possible to run [Java Apps on heroku](https://java.heroku.com/) but I cannot find  description of how to make Jenkins run on Heroku anywhere.

Very grateful for hints.

Comment: While you probably can, you would have to run any builds on other servers.

Comment: @ZekeSonxx Can you please elaborate a bit more? What do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Easy enough to load Jenkins as a heroku app

1) pom.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
  Just need a plain and mostly empty pom.xml for Orchard to detect that this is a Java application
-->
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <artifactId>helloworld</artifactId>
</project>
```

2. A Procfile that looks like this:

## Only listen on http; disable ajp and https

web: java -jar jenkins.war --httpPort=$PORT --ajp13Port=-1 --httpsPort=-1

3. The jenkins.war file.

The real problem becomes that jenkins uses the local filesystem for storage and the local storage is not persistent in the Heroku environment so you have to manage your configuration regularly or using the github storage add-on.

Comment: @jackYork  I have been struggling with getting jenkins to work properly even if the dynos get restarted but all my jobs and settings start from the beginning where I have to sign up again in jenkins as admin, how can I fix this?

Comment: Heroku doesnt supports it, your data will get lost everytime dynos get restarted